# Materia-ui and typescript No overload matches this call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm converting a js component that uses Material-ui to typescript and I ran into a problem. This part was rendering a tile-like image in which the *component* prop was overridden plus additional *to* prop to make a proper clickable link.

The error I get is :
*TS2769: No overload matches this call.*

Here is the code I'm using:

Importing statement:

```
import GridListTile from '@material-ui/core/GridListTile';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

And in render function I have:

```
<GridListTile
  component={Link} <<-- here I get the error
  to={'/some-address'}
>
  // other components
</GridListTile>
```

I can silence the error by passing `as any`, but then it complains about *to* prop!

```
<GridListTile
  component={Link as any} <<-- won't complain
  to={'/some-address'} <<-- but now here I get the error
>
  // other components
</GridListTile>
```

I want to be able to use Material-ui components and be able to pass another component and the props I want.
I came across some solutions which were hacks, what is the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: Couldn't manage to reproduce the error you faced. Could you provide an online demo? https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-sea-edbt1?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @keikai Here is a sandbox, which only shows a warning on `to` prop, but my app will throw an error! https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-react-material-ui-cq8e1?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Still can't find the error `TS2769: No overload matches this call.` you mentioned. By the way, you need `@types/react-router-dom` for the ts type of `react-router-dom`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug in `material-ui` that was fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/commit/701e3ad76b788a50ea83aeb8516ed303c2435bd0), and I've checked the latest version (v4.9.13) and it was okay.

So upgrading to the latest version will fix this issue.